# Pass values from TWO text boxes in a php file to another php file with a single submit button

Tags: php, html, textbox, submit

I am trying to have two textboxes, and get the values entered in them in another php file. But, Is it possible to have a single submit button that submits both the values ?

**To get value from page1.php to page2.php**

I have this to pass value in one text box:

```
<form action='page2.php' method='post'>
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" NAME='search' VALUE ="search">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Search">
</form>
```

and on Page2.php, I get the value using:

```
$sname = $_POST['search'];
```

But, how about having two text boxes, and passing the values of both simultaneously?

```
<form action='page2.php' method='post'>
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" NAME='search1' VALUE ="search1">
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" NAME='search2' VALUE ="search2">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Search1","Search2">
</form>
```

And on page2.php:

```
$name1=$_POST['search1'];
$name2=$_POST['search2'];
```

I know I am not doing it right on the SUBMIT part. What are the changes that I should do to get it right?

Comment: That should just work...

Comment: Have you tried the code to see what happens?

Comment: Code looks neat, shouldnt be causing a prob,btw have you tried ?

Comment: only thing that I see that looks strange is that the submit button on the second example should be `<input type="Submit" name="Submit1" value='Search'/>` Then page2.php should receive both values as you described (as separate elements in the $_POST array)

Answer (score 0):

Your form should be like this:

```
<form action='page2.php' method='post'>
    <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" NAME='search1' VALUE ="search1">
    <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" NAME='search2' VALUE ="search2">
    <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Search">
</form>
```

The value for `submit` button is not related to the input box names. Probably the similarity of the names misguided you in the first example. In html forms, when a user clicks on `submit` buttons, all the fields defined in the form will be sent to the target file specified in the `action` attributed. Then, in the target file those sent variables can be retrieved based on the `method` you have defined in your form.